# Searching values in local storage using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I am trying to search for values which are inside of the local storage. before i had a search which only searches for hard coded values now i'm trying to implement local storage with the search function

```
<div id="list">
        <input type="text" v-model="search">
        <ol>
            <li v-for="(items, key) in groupedItems">
                <p>{{ key }}</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script>

        var list = new Vue({
            el: '#list',
            data: {
                search: '',
                items: {


                    var: retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("todos")


                },
                computed: {
                    groupedItems() {

                        const arr = {};
                        //search
                        var searchResult = this.items.filter(todo => {
                            return todo.retrievedData.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;

                        });
                        //grouping
                        for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
                            const key = searchResult[i].retrievedData;
                            if (arr[key]) {
                                arr[key].push(searchResult[i])
                            } else {
                                arr[key] = [searchResult[i]];

                            }
                        }
                        return arr
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    </script>
```

local storage values:

```
{topic: "web", price: "22", place: "town", time_length: "22hrs", edit: false}
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: i'm trying to get the search to work with local storage other then searching for hard coded items

Comment: Where does the solution you tried fail? What's the error message?

Comment: There’s no error message when I try replace the hard coded items with local storage it’s just not displaying anything

Comment: Have you tried debugging your computed function? Go through it line by line and find out where it fails. Also you should be using Arrays (`[]`) instead of objects (`{}`)